# What information does a Kotlin error message give?

Tags: kotlin

I have a question about Kotlin error messages. Let's say I have a simple error caused by not closing a print statement:

```
fun main() {
  println("Hello."
}
```

and the error returned is:

```
Hello.kt:2:54: error: expecting ')'
  println("Hello."
                                                     ^
```

Hello.kt is the file.
2 is the line the error lives.
My question is what does 54 mean?

Comment: Line 2, *character* 54.

Comment: The 54th symbol on that line

Comment: `2:54:` means line 2, 54th character. `error: expecting ')'` -missing ')'